# Ionic capacitor npx sync não funcionando

Tags: android, ionic, ionic2, ionic3, apk

quando eu adiciono um plugin, eu preciso rodar o comando:

```
npx cap sync
```

Para que ele possa carregar o plugin, porém estou recebendo o erro abaixo: 
[image: Erro]

Comment: Parece problema de permissão do diretório. Tente dar permissão manualmente.

Comment: Mesmo assim o problema persiste, to tenso com isso já